# Unable to find items added to database - undefined method `find'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently fetching some items ([REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)) from this external API in the background ([DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record)) and then saving them to the database. The plan is to check using a Rails route whether or not the items have been saved to the database, ie. when it's safe to start pulling them in to the client via Ajax.

But how come `Affiliate.find(params[:url])` in the controller isn't working?

```
Started GET "/check_items_loaded" at 2015-06-06 00:00:24 +0000
Processing by MainController#check_items_loaded as */* 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for Affiliate:Class): 
  app/controllers/main_controller.rb:8:in `check_items_loaded'
```

**Live app which you can run on the fly**: http://runnable.com/VXIdQ6KuRrYPdhKs/rest-client-ajax

**routes.rb**

```
get '/check_items_loaded', to: 'main#check_items_loaded', as: :check_items_loaded
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end

  def check_items_loaded
    @items_status = Affiliate.find(params[:url])
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.js
    end
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      affiliate = Affiliate.find_or_create_by(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
      affiliate.save
    end
  end
end
```

**20150604213141_add_items_to_affiliates.rb**

```
class AddItemsToAffiliates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:affiliates) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is an `ActiveRecord` method. You've declared your class like this:

```
class Affiliate
```

If you want Affiliate to have ActiveRecord methods, you're going to have to do this:

```
class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
```